# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a ruby app similar to reddit and have run into this error while adding user sign-up functionality.  I have a commit view with the following line of code that is causing the error:

```
<%= button_to "Yes", {controller: 'users', 
                          action: 'create',
                          params: params}, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
```

To fix the error I changed the code like so:

```
<%= button_to "Yes", {
                      controller: 'users', 
                          action: 'create',   
                          params: {  
                               user { 
                                     name: @user.name,  
                                    email: @user.email,  
                                 password: @user.password, 
                    password_confirmation: @user.password_confirmation 

                                     }  
                                   } 
                      },  class: 'btn btn-success' %>
```

This fixes the problem but I would like to understand why the first line doesn't work and get advice on the best way to implement this.

the error gets thrown on `@user.name =params[:user][:name]`.
Here is the full def in users controller:

```
def create  
  @user = User.new  
  @user.name = params[:user][:name]  
  @user.email = params[:user][:email] 
  @user.password = params[:user][:password]  
  @user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password_confirmation]  
end
```

From my server log I can see that user has been changed to a long string in params:

```
    Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"xSeWlcW6Ix5kciNGi2/xAep2aRq0CmefI6ln‌​ieQutlolAsk/qXM+mGvW‌​ixvNfTMedHnstWDd29mb‌​MThGF1FCqg==", "commit"=>"Sign up", "user"=>"email=ja%40j.com&name=jasonj&password=jjjjjj&passwo‌​rd_confirmation=jjjj‌​jj", "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

Comment: You probably are using strong parameters, show your controller code and exact snippet where the error was raised..

Comment: can you show us the value of params in your view?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should convert your params hash with this command 'symbolize_keys'

Example:

```
{"test"=>"hb", "test"=>"hb" }.symbolize_keys
```

return

```
{test: "hb", test: "hb" }
```